# Deploying NodeJs to Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: node.js, deployment, azure-service-fabric, codeship

Has Anyone had any experience to deploy a RESTFul nodejs service to service fabric?

What tools are possible, Jenkins or even code ship

Answer (score 0):

Found a knowledge base article from Microsoft here, looks like you just package it up and drop in into a folder location for Service fabric to consume

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a RESTFul node.js service to service fabric you need to have a Node.js host - to actually run your JavaScript. There are three options for  doing that:

1. Create custom executable and deploy it as a Service Fabric guest. Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-multiple-apps
2. Use Docker containers on Service Fabric: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-package-containers
3. Use SupercondActor to host Node.js API natively inside Service Fabric stateless service. See GitHub repo: https://github.com/SupercondActor/platform-app-angular

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16 for deploying Restful node+mongo app in service fabric cluster. After packaging my app and after installation complete I am getting error  `Error occurred in request HTTPSConnectionPool Max retry exceeded (Cause by response error (too many 504 response))`. So the application is not getting deployed

Comment: The SupercondActor works only for Windows-based service fabric cluster

Comment: Yes, I know that , I am using Docker container and I have deployed it now with port 3000 node app. But I am not getting hello world message when I am running from cluster url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710717/deployed-node-application-not-working-on-cluster-service-fabric

Comment: Dicker is a great typo :)