# Deployed node application not working on cluster service fabric

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-service-fabric

I have deployed an application on service fabric cluster and deployment is also successful and the node is also healthy.

I am using Ubuntu 16 for deployment. I have used docker containerization as given in azure service fabric container document.

My node app is running on port 3000 , so I have created docker file with same port number. When I am running my deployed app with port 3000 `https://cluster.useast.______azure.com:3000` , it is not running.

I have also make changes on *applicationmanifest.xml* file and *servicemanifest.xml* file with same port number and *uri: http*

When I am running the same node application on localhost it is successful. with hello world! as a message that I have provided in the app.

Any idea why I am not able to display message on browser with deployed link ?

Comment: Did you configure the Azure Load Balancer to forward port 3000 to the cluster?

Comment: @LoekD No, I didn't . I am new in azure . How can I do that ? If I created a cluster then a load balancer must automatically have been created I guess. Also I have defined endpoint on `ServiceManifest.xml`

Comment: yes, it comes with the cluster deployment. Add a load-balancing [rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/create-load-balancer-rule).  Pls consider using a reverse proxy like Traefik, or [Api Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-api-management) to access your services, instead of exposing individual services directly.

Comment: @LoekD I don't have back-end end point. I have set the port to `3000` under `http` under `AppPortProbe1`. Should I leave the `path` for back-end ?